# How can I remove the timestamp from a filename in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a file which has a line in it as:

```
 /hosting/logs/U01-ecom-SIT01/CU01-DC05-IFIO_SIT01_NU01-nc3sz1ecmas11/waslogs/SystemOut_10.01.21_16.54.18.log`
```

I need a script which would read this line and remove the time stamp from it, that is:

```
 10.01.21_16.54.18
```

The script should print the filename without the timestamp and holding the full path, that is:

```
 /hosting/logs/U01-ecom-SIT01/CU01-DC05-IFIO_SIT01_NU01-nc3sz1ecmas11/waslogs/SystemOut.log`
```

Please help as I'm unable to pattern match and output the file path without the timestamp.

Comment: that's a pretty non-standard timestamp format. Are you that short of space that you can't spare two extra digits to have a four-digit year?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "/hosting/logs/U01-ecom-SIT01/CU01-DC05-IFIO_SIT01_NU01-nc3sz1ecmas11/waslogs/SystemOut_10.01.21_16.54.18.log" | 
  perl -pe "s/_\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d_\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d//;"
```

Answer (score 1):

`$ perl -e 's{_\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{2}_\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{2}}{} and print for @ARGV' /hosting/logs/U01-ecom-SIT01/CU01-DC05-IFIO_SIT01_NU01-nc3sz1ecmas11/waslogs/SystemOut_10.01.21_16.54.18.log`

Answer (score 1):

Path shortened to prevent scrolling:

```
$ cat paths
CU01-DC05-IFIO_SIT01_NU01-nc3sz1ecmas11/waslogs/SystemOut_10.01.21_16.54.18.log

$ perl -pe 's/(_(\d\d(\.\d\d){2})){2}\.log$/.log/' paths
CU01-DC05-IFIO_SIT01_NU01-nc3sz1ecmas11/waslogs/SystemOut.log
```

The timestamp is made up of 2 sequences that look like `_##.##.##`. The subsequences end with 2 sequences of `.##`. These are the roles of the `{2}` quantifiers.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(<>){
    @s = split /\// ;
    $fullpath=join("/",splice @s , 0, $#s);
    @a = split /[_.]/ ,$s[-1];
    $newfile="$fullpath/$a[0].$a[-1]";
    print $newfile."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following coding

```
 use strict;
    use warnings;
  my $var; $var=/hosting/logs/U01-ecom-SIT01/CU01-DC05-IFIO_SIT01_NU01-nc3sz1ecmas11/waslogs/SystemOut_10.01.21_16.54.18.log";
    $var=~s/_\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d//g;
    # $var=~s/_10\.01\.21_16\.54\.18//g; # You can use this way also 
    print "$var\n";
```